# Getting Error while Creating a new React App from Terminal

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

While using the below command, I am getting few errors.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

The errors I am getting are

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...8olCMjOZDx5OzCM3r6Cqh'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\mechi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-26T18_53_12_343Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try with the next:

`npm cache clean --force`

regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is npm install error, try clearing the npm cache and install again.

npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

First use 
`npm cache clean --force`
then  you can `npx create-react-app my-app` or `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting it into two commands.  Install create-react-app first, then create the app

```
npx  create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

Failing that

1. update/uninstall yarn etc..
2. update/uninstall create-react-app